In a vacuum, what gas(es) emanate from ilmenite when heated degree by degree to very high temperatures (complete sublimation)?
In a vacuum, ilmenite $\ce{FeTiO3},$ like all matter, sublimates to gas(es) if heated to a high enough temperature. If our (already purified) ilmenite sample (at $\pu{0 Pa}$ pressure and no reactants present whatsoever) were heated, a fraction of a degree at a time, right up to the sublimation of the entire sample, which gas (element or compound) would sublimate first and at what temperature? Which second? Which gas (element or compound) would be the last to sublimate? Perhaps nothing would change and the only sublimation product would be ilmenite gas?

If a understand your question correctly, you would like to know whether ilmenite gets decomposed when heated at high temperature, and how. Am I right ?

Yes you have indeed perfectly understood my question, thanks! Let's not forget the vacuum though...implying 0 pressure and the absence of any reacting elements or compounds-not even an ineert gas...

The following might be a starting point: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063319301709

Checked out https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063319301709 as suggested by Buck Thorn. Very interesting, showing how oxygen and titanium oxide can be derived by heating ilmenite in presence of hydrogen. Still, what about a pure vacuum? Can even trace amounts of other gases besides ilmenite be obtained by heating ilmenite under pure vacuum conditions with no reactants present?
